# Initializing google map with kml layer using Angular: InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map

Tags: angular, google-maps, kml

I'm trying to initialize a google map with a kml layer. I have verified that the KML layer is working, and if I use vanilla JS I can get this to work (see fiddle of working: https://jsfiddle.net/x00t510d/2/), however I'm using angular and am initializing the map in ngOnInit().

The following code produces a result of "InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map".

```
    export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('gmap') gmapElement: any;
  map: google.maps.Map;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    let mapProp: any = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.475, -73.212),
      zoom: 13,    
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP     
    };

     let ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/freeparkingburlington/home/freeParking.kml',
      map: mapProp
    });

  return this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);
  }  

}
```

The map does get initialized but the layer does not. Does anyone have insight on how to more effectively use the KML layer in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is initializing the map, and the kml layer on the ngOnInit lifecycle hook. the map should be initialized in ngOnInit(), and once that has been loaded call ngAfterContentInit to add the layer to the map.

See code here:

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild('gmap') gmapElement: any;
  map: google.maps.Map;
  //ctaLayer: google.maps.KmlLayer;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    let mapProp: any = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.475, -73.212),
      zoom: 13,    
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP     
    };

  return this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);
  }  

  ngAfterContentInit(){
    let ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/freeparkingburlington/home/freeParking.kml',
      map: this.map
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: The variable gmapElement, what type is it? Why you do a return on ngOnInit? I ask you this because I can't reproduce the example you're pointing out.

Comment: @drielnox looking at this after a few years, looks like i just didn't understand how state works haha! not sure why i would've put that return statement in there other than i didn't know what i was doing. What issue are you running into?

Comment: It's a problem quite similar to the one discussed here. After some in-depth research, I noticed that Angular's Google Maps component has not implemented the API for the KML layer in the NPM package. You can achieve placing a KML layer by doing a mixed implementation between JS and TS, but this is exactly something I want to avoid. And besides, it's very difficult to get the Map<Element> that is required to instantiate a KmlLayer, because the GoogleMap object (see documentation) doesn't have a property or something to get the native HTML element.